# Mouse Wheel Lines not honored/saved after stable reboot

Tags: mouse-wheel

After changing the mouse lines per scroll preference in Windows 7 Mouse Control Panel from three to eight and rebooting the preference is set back to three, how do I force Windows to honor the preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use *X-Mouse Button Control* and after manually setting the wheel preference in *X-Mouse Button Control* and rebooting the Windows Mouse Control Panel setting was set to eight instead of three.

There are lots of programs that interact with mice and trackpads, if someone has something, especially a trackpad on a laptop then they are very likely running mouse-related software that can be disabled via msconfig.